# nginx push rtmp stream to ffmpeg

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg, rtmp

On my Raspberry Pi with camera module, I try to setup a web-based streaming platform. I want to preview the stream in my browser and use CGI scripts to start/stop broadcasting to youtube (,...).

This is how I did the streaming setup so far:

[image]

Nginx puts up an RTMP application `webcam`. This is where I'll send the camera and audio stream usig ffmpeg. It publishes the stream as HLS for the web preview. It's also pushing the stream to another application `source`. That's where I want to (occasionally) hook up another ffmpeg process for broadcasting to youtube (,...) RTMP end points.

I initiate the stream using ffmpeg like this:

```
ffmpeg -loglevel debug -f v4l2 -framerate 15 -video_size 1280x720 -input_format h264 -i /dev/video0 -f alsa -i hw:2 -codec:v copy -g 15 -codec:a aac -b:a 128k -ar 44100 -strict experimental -f flv "rtmp://localhost:1935/webcam/hhart"
```

So far everything works fine. I can preview the HLS stream using a video.js viewer on my website (also served by nginx).

Now I want to start another ffmpeg process for broadcasting to my youtube channel, hooked up to the `source` application like this:

```
ffmpeg -loglevel debug -f flv -listen 1 -i rtmp://localhost:1935/source/hhart -c copy 'rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/<KEY>'
```

(in the final setup, launching and killing this process will be done via CGI scripts)

This is what ffmpeg returns:

```
Opening an input file: rtmp://localhost:1935/source/hhart.
[flv @ 0x2032480] Opening 'rtmp://localhost:1935/source/hhart' for reading
[rtmp @ 0x2032a10] No default whitelist set
[tcp @ 0x20330f0] No default whitelist set
```

and then... nothing happens. There's no stream coming in at Youtube studio, but there are no error messages either.

Some other tests I did:

1. from the `webcam` application, push directly to the Youtube RTMP => that works! (but it's not what I want, because I want the HLS stream to be online always, but the broadcasting only when I'm going live.)
2. from VLC display the stream at `rtmp://localhost:1935/source/hhart` => similar to ffmpeg, there's no error message, the progress bar keeps loading.

So I have the impression that there is *something* going on, but there's no actual data transmitted.

RTMP section in nginx.conf:

```
rtmp {                                                                     
    server {                                                               
        listen 1935;                                                       
        chunk_size 4000;                                                   
                                                                           
        application webcam {                                               
            live on;                                                       
            hls on;                                                        
            hls_path /Services/Webcam/HLSStream;                           
            hls_fragment 3;                                                
            hls_playlist_length 60;                                        
            #deny play all;                                                 
            push rtmp://localhost:1935/source/;                            
            #push rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/<KEY>;
        }                                                                  
                                                                           
        application source {                                               
            live on;                                                       
            record off;                                                    
        }                                                                  
    }                                                                      
}
```

Of course, I may be totally on the wrong track, so any suggestions how I can realize my requirements in a better way, are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

OK, I recompiled nginx with `--with-debug` and that got me to a solution.

Rather than pushing the stream to another application, I have to push the stream to an RTMP address on another port, and there the second ffmpeg process can pick it up. And it seems to be better to use `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`.

Like this:

```
rtmp {                                                                     
    server {                                                               
        listen 1935;                                                       
        chunk_size 4000;                                                   
                                                                           
        application webcam {                                               
            live on;                                                       
            hls on;                                                        
            hls_path /Services/Webcam/HLSStream;                           
            hls_fragment 3;                                                
            hls_playlist_length 60;                                        
            #deny play all;                                                 
            push rtmp://127.0.0.1:1936/test/;  # ADDED
            record off;                                                    
        }                                                                  
    }                                                                      
}
```

Launching the broadcast to youtube:

```
ffmpeg -loglevel debug -f flv -listen 1 -i rtmp://127.0.0.1:1936/test/ -c copy -f flv 'rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/<KEY>'
```

Now my HLS stream is always online, and I can control broadcasting to youtube by launching/killing the second ffmpeg process.